# Unable to bind Header Template with L2S IQueryable list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have method that is returning IQuerable given below:

```
internal IQueryable<TradeLeads> GetLeadsByCategory(int categoryId)
        {
            return
                _context.BuySells.Where(bs => bs.CategoryId == categoryId).OrderBy(bs => bs.CreationDate).Select(
                    bs => new TradeLeads
                              {
                                  Id = bs.Id,
                                  BuySellTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(bs.BuySellTypeId.ToString()) ,
                                  Description = bs.Description,
                                  Flag = bs.Company.Country1.Flag,
                                  MembershipType = bs.Company.MembershipType,
                                  IsUsingSmsNotifications = bs.Company.IsUsingSMSNotifications,
                                  IsVerified = bs.Company.IsVerified,
                                  ProductImagePath = bs.ProductImagePath,
                                  ProductName = bs.ProductName,
                                  CompanyName = bs.Company.CompanyName,
                                  CompanyId = Convert.ToInt32(bs.CompanyId.ToString()),
                                  PostedDate = bs.CreationDate
                              });
        }
```

All fields are having values. I am binding BuySellTypeId in the header template of the repeater control. ASPX is given below, which is in Usercontrol.

```
<HeaderTemplate>
        <div class="grdheader">
            <div class="hdrText">
                <h3 id="h3TypeName">
                    </h3> <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="HidTypeId" Value='<%#Eval("BuySellTypeId") %>'/>
            </div>
            <div class="hdrMore">
                <a href='<%#string.Format("ViewAll.aspx?t={0}",Eval("BuySellTypeId"))%>'>
                    <img src="cdn/images/more.png" />
                    View More </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </HeaderTemplate>
```

I am binding repeater from its parent page something like this. First I changed the protection level of the repeater from protected to public, so that I can access it from any where, without casting or finding from  parent page.

```
  private void BindAllBuyAndSellLeads(int categoryId)
        {
            var repo = new LeadsRepository();
            var list = repo.GetLeadsByCategory(categoryId);
            BindGrid(1, Leads1.LeadsGrid, list);
            BindGrid(2, Leads2.LeadsGrid, list);
        }
        private static void BindGrid(int leadTypeId, Repeater gv, IQueryable<Core.Helper.TradeLeads> list)
        {
            var query = (from p in list
                         where p.BuySellTypeId == leadTypeId
                         select p).ToList();
            Common.BindGrid(query, gv);
        }
```

here Leads1 and Leads2 are the user control Leads.ascx. That is same usercontrol is placed at two places on page. But i am getting empty while binding. Please help , where and what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding in a header will never work.  Binding is for ItemTemplate only; you can programmably set the value in the header, but realize the repeater is for binding multiple rows of data; there are multiple items, but only one header.  Which **BuySellTypeId** should be used?  The first one?  The last one?  There is no way for the repeater to tell, so you would have to programmably set the value.